# Is it safe to downcast if the derived class contains methods only (no member variables)

Tags: c++, downcast

Well, I recently ran into the case where I downcasted, by distraction as follows:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    PyObject *GetPyObj() { return m_obj; }
    void SetPyObj(PyObject *obj) { m_obj = obj }
private:
    PyObject *m_obj;
};
```

This class adding an additional `m_obj` attribute to the Base class, unfortunately I had, somewhere in my code a totally unsafe cast like this:

```
Derived *node = <Derived *>some_ObjectPtr;
// Where "some_ObjectPtr" had been created as a "Base*" in the first place.
```

Which was leading to some arbitrary behavior sometimes when I was calling `SetPyObj()`. Thanks to `Valgrind`, I've been able to identify that I was "writing beyond the end of my object" and to locate the problem:

```
...
==5679== 
==5679== Invalid write of size 8
==5679==    at 0x812DB01: elps::Derived::SetPyObj(_object*) (ALabNetBinding.cpp:27)
==5679==    by 0x8113B2C: __pyx_f_5cyelp_12PyLabNetwork_Populate(__pyx_obj_5cyelp_PyLabNetwork*, int, int) (cyelp.cpp:10112)
...
```

My first attempt was to shift `m_obj` to the Base class as a `void*`, and convert the `SetPyObj()` into this :

```
void SetPyObj(PyObject *obj) {
  this->SetObj(obj);
}
```

where `Base::SetObj(obj)` looks like this :

```
void SetObj(void *obj);
```

(I chose `void *`, because, for some good reasons, the type PyObject wasn't available from the Base definition...)

This way I was writing into the parent class, and the problem disappeared, but still...

I am not at ease with this kind of manipulations and not really satisfied with the workaround (It doesn't look like a good practice, I can smell it!).

So, here's my question:

Is it "acceptable" to do what I did as long as I extend `Base` by a class with additional methods only (no additional member variables)?

If not, is it acceptable to downcast in such a context anyway? Which are the cases where downcasting is acceptable (I mean other than having created `some_ObjectPtr` as a `Derived*` in the first place)?

If yes, what would have been an elegant way to deal with that case?

Note: using features like `dynamic_cast<>` was not an option in my environment (not available with Cython) and I am not sure it would have helped anyway.

Bonus secondary question: Could you explain how the size in memory of a given instance of a class is handled? I can clearly see that, in my example, the additional attribute overflows by its size (64 bits), but adding a method seems safe (does it mean that if the derived class contains only additional methods both Derived and Base classes will produce objects of the exact same size?).

I hope I made my concerns clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to downcast an object pointer to `Derived*` only if this object has been created as `Derived` or any class inherited from `Derived`. In other cases it can't be safe. It may work for some implementations, but it is not allowed by the language.

> (I chose void *, because, for some good reasons, the type PyObject
>   wasn't available from the Base definition...)

It's not a good reason. You should never use `void*` in C++. You should place a forward declaration of PyObject in top of your header. Considering real declaration of PyObject, forward declaration statement should look like the following:

```
typedef struct _object PyObject;
```

Comment: All right for the downcast part, but regarding th void* thing, Base is part of an independent shared library which I want to keep independent from any Python specific stuffs... This is a good reason. Why not void* in C++ ? Is that also discouraged by the language ?

Comment: `void*` is used in C because it's the only way to do several things. C++ provides better ways to do that things, there is no need in `void*` in C++. It also provides no compile-time checking, so it's much better to use C++ ways. In your particular case, I would create some class named `MyObject` and use `Base::setObj(MyObject*)`. For `Derived` class I would create another class `MyPyObject` that extends `MyObject` and hold `PyObject*` pointer. It will ensure that you pass only correct objects to  `Base::setObj`, it will protect you against stupid mistakes like passing `int*` to setObj.

Comment: All right, that makes sense, explained that way. Thanks for the advices. And, in a more general consideration, what would be the C++ way, if I do want to deal with really undefined type reference. Dealing with a user defined object storage / reference, by example ? If I want him (the user) to be allowed to store an `int*` as well as any kind of object he created himself ? Should I provide a base dummy object, and `force` him to derivate from it instead ? Pardon me if I'm a bit C++ dumb...

Comment: I think templates are the best option. For example, `std::vector<T>` works with any user defined class `T`.

Comment: That makes sense too. Templates are not that easy to use with `Cython` (only partially supported) but it seems doable to me.